# Change post url depending on language

Tags: wordpress

I have a Web page that has a blog. It has a static home page, and you can access the menu using the top menu.

When I visit the main blog, it looks like:

> www.mysite.com/blog

When I go to the translated blog (in this case, the English version) it looks like:

> www.mysite.com/blog-2

I want it to look like:

> www.mysite.com/blog/en/

I used permalinks like this:

> /blog/%postname%/

I tried:

> /blog/%lang%/%postname%/
>   With no luck...

How can I make it sensitive to languages?

**EDIT:** Plugins I'm using:

- Polylang
- Lingotek

Comment: Which language plugin do you use?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my question.

Comment: Mh. Please take a look into your seetings (settings -> language) there should be some settings to change the URL.

Comment: Yes, I found it. Under: Settings -> Language -> Settings (again). Thanks!

Comment: Can ou post it as an answer so I can upvote you?

Comment: I did it. Thank you - I upvoted your post too. Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the plugin: `polylang`

So you can change the URL in the settings.

Take a look into the settings of polylang:

```
Settings -> Language -> Settings
```